# Why does raised cosine pulse through Butterworth filter introduce (significant) ISI?

Tags: filters, digital-communications, modulation, impulse-response

Here is a simple MATLAB experiment:

```
alpha = 1;
R = 10;
[b,a] = butter(7,alpha*1/R);
x = resample(sign(randn(100,1)),R,1,0); % zero-order-hold
y = filter(b,a,x);
eyediagram(y, 2*R);
```

With channel twice the bandwidth than the pulses (`alpha=2`) the eye diagram looks clean. The first thing I am concerned that the eye diagram at the critical bandwidth (`alpha=1`, i.e. channel bandwidth is bitrate/2) still looks reasonably clean (little bit ISI but not too much):

[image: Eye Diagram NRZ]

I would have expected significant ISI at the critical bandwidth.

Now instead of using rectangular pulses, I use a raised cosine filter:

```
 hcos = rcosdesign(0, 30, R);
 x = upfirdn(sign(randn(1000,1)), hcos, R);
```

Now the eye diagram is significantly worse:

[image: Eye Diagram raised cosine]

I would expect the result to be **significantly** better. I played with all possible rolloff factors 0...1 and number of symbols. I also tried cutting the signal at beginning/end, thinking it may be the initial transient. No changes.

What is going on here?

(Additional info: I do not want to simulate TX/RX with raised cosine but assess a channel without having to use an equalizer - in simulation. One way to do this is using an equalizer or just using a pulse shape that works close to the theoretical bandwidth - that should be raised cosine with a low beta).

Comment: You can create a raised-cosine pulse (instead of root raised-cosine) by running `rcosdesign(beta,30,R,normal)`. Can you also try setting the rolloff factor `beta` to 0.25, 0.5, and 0.75? Setting `beta=0` means you're actually using a sinc pulse, which is notoriously difficult to get right since it requires a very long duration to maintain orthogonality, and this introduces numerical approximation errors.

Answer (score 1):

That's because Matlab's [rcosdesign](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/rcosdesign.html) creates a [root-raised-cos filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-raised-cosine_filter), not a raised cos filter. If you want no ISI (ie meet Nyquist's criterion), you need to do the match filtering of the reception part :

```
%%
alpha = 1;
R = 10;
hcos = rcosdesign(0.25, 30, R);
x = upfirdn(sign(randn(1000,1)), hcos, R);
y = upfirdn(x, hcos, 1, R);
eyediagram(x, 2*R);
hold on
eyediagram(y, 2*R);
```

[image: eyediagram RRC]

eye of x

[image: eyediagram RC]

eye of y

Comment: Very excited about your answer, thanks! However, it still does not work: When I change the shape to `normal`, the eye diagram looks the same as for rectangular pulses (but it should look way better/no ISI). Similarly if I add the filter in your code between the upfirdn lines. I want to assess a channel without using equalization/ISI and hence - for simulation - use the raised cosine shape. Would you be able to change your answer to include the filter (operating at sample rate, NOT the symbol rate)